# How to use axios.patch to edit data in the database?

Tags: laravel, axios, vuejs3, httprequest

I have not been taught much in classes about coding, so most of it is self-taught and collaborations with friends, so please be patient. So my friends and I have been working on a project using axios.patch. We have made it possible for axios.get to work, but the axios.the patch does not even touch our database.

Here is the code for my axios.patch

```js
methods: {
  sendPatchRequest() {
    axios
      .get("events/" + this.$route.params.id)
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data.data;
        axios
          .patch("events/" + this.$route.params.id, {
            data: data.title,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch((erorr) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
```

Here is the button for calling the function for the PATCH

```html
<FilledButton id="updateButton" class="w-[100px]" text="CONFIRM" @click="sendPatchRequest"></FilledButton>
```

Here is our controller.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class EventsController extends Controller
{
    private $MSG_ERR_ID_NOT_FOUND = 'ID did not match any of the user found in database.';
    private $MSG_ERR_ADDITIONAL_PROPS = 'Model does not contain properties found in request';
    private $MSG_SUC_ID_FOUND = 'User found.';
    private $MSG_SUC_UPDATE = 'User successfully updated.';
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $events = Event::all();
        return response()->json($events, 200, ['application/json']);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       
        $request->validate([
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'author' => 'required',
            'event_type' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required',
            'ref' => 'required'
        ]);

        $event = new Event;
        $event->fill($request->except(['user_id']));
        $event->user_id = $request->user_id;

        if($event->save()) {
            return response($event, 200, ['application/json']);
        } else {
            return response("Error in saving data", 400, ['application/json']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Event  $event
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $event = Event::find($id);

        if($event) {
            return response($this->generateRes($event, 200, $this->MSG_SUC_ID_FOUND), 200, ['application/json']);
        } else {
            return response($this->generateRes($event, 400, $this->MSG_ERR_ID_NOT_FOUND), 400, ['application/json']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Event  $event
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $msg = '';
        $status = '';
        $err = false;

        $request->validate([
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'author' => 'required',
            'event_type' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required',
            'ref' => 'required'
        ]);

        $event = Event::find($id);
        $event->fill($request->except(['user_id']));
        $event->user_id = $request->user_id;

        if($event->save()) {
            $msg = $this->MSG_SUC_ID_FOUND;
            $status = 200;
            return response($this->generateRes($event, $status, $msg), 200, ['application/json']);
        } else {
            return response("Error in saving data", 400, ['application/json']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Event  $event
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $event = Event::find($id);
        $event->is_deleted = true;

        if($event->save()) {
            return response("Succesfully deleted data!", 200, ['application/json']);
        } else {
            return response("Error in deleting data", 400, ['application/json']);
        }
    }

    public function generateRes($data, $status, $msg) {
        $res = [
            'data' => $data,
            'status' => $status,
            'msg' => $msg
        ];
        return $res;
    }
}
```

I tried to change the

```
data: data.title
```

into

```
data: title
```

or even experimenting with it from other documents and youtube videos that I tried to understand. But that first code was the one closest to what I have achieved.

**What I want to happen** is that if I change anything in my input box and click the confirm button, it will update the database with what I changed.

**What I get**

[image]

[image]

Here is line 155

[image]

Comment: What you're sending from the front-end is not matching what you wait for on the backend (translating the given error). Check the network tab to see what you're sending (if the front-end is the cause) and you can use Postman to double check that your backend works well. I have no experience with Laravel unfortunately, sorry.

Comment: You need to submit all the required fields, see the response for the list of failed rules. If you want to do partial update you will need to update the backend to allow it, aka not requiring those field in the update.

Comment: @kissu I checked the network tab and it is requiring data

{
  "user_id": [
    "The user id field is required."
  ],
  "title": [
    "The title field is required."
  ],
  "content": [
    "The content field is required."
  ],
  "image": [
    "The image field is required."
  ],
  "author": [
    "The author field is required."
  ],
  "event_type": [
    "The event type field is required."
  ],
  "location": [
    "The location field is required."
  ],
  "date": [
    "The date field is required."
  ],
  but I thought axios.patch just updates the certain ones

Comment: @complicatedProgramming axios.patch send a patch request that's it, you still need to have all the required fields, or don't require them in your update in the first place. Also you submit the title value, but you still need the key 'title', so it's `data: {title: data.title, ... other fields here ...}`

Comment: @Lk77 It worked thank you! It seemed that the controller code had a required them. you were very helpful. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

Your JS method is kinda weird, because it fetches an event from the api and then posts the same event back to the api as soon as it is retrieved ?

You should have different methods for fetching and patching.

But to make single attribute updates work, in your update method, you should put sometimes|required behind the title field to allow sending only the title ... or probably behind everything if you want every attribute to be updated seperately

Comment: There was actually a template in which taught me how to retrieve and update the same event back. Is it a bad practice? I had another axios.get before that method but that was for fetching the data.

 mounted() {
        axios.get('events/' + this.$route.params.id).then(
            (response) => {
            this.events = response.data.data,
            console.log("event"),
            console.log(this.events)
            }
        )
    },

where the data is stored at a variable called events:[],